# Behavior of range function in numba-compiled functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, numba

I just realized that there is a strange behavior using `jit` decorator and `range` function together. Better than a long speech, consider the following simple code :

```
@nb.njit(['float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int32, int32)'])
def range1(a, b, nx, nz):
    for ix in range(5, nx-5):
        for iz in range(5, nz-5):
            b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz+1] - a[ix-1, iz-1])
    return b


@nb.njit(['float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int32, int32, int32, int32)'])
def range2(a, b, ix1, ix2, iz1, iz2):
    for ix in range(ix1, ix2):
        for iz in range(iz1, iz2):
            b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz+1] - a[ix-1, iz-1])
    return b


@nb.njit(['float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int32, int32, int32, int32)'])
def range3(a, b, ix1, ix2, iz1, iz2):
    for ix in range(ix1, ix2):
        for iz in range(5, iz2):
            b[ix, iz] = 0.5*(a[ix+1, iz+1] - a[ix-1, iz-1])
    return b


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('Numba : {}'.format(nb.__version__))
    print('Numpy : {}\n'.format(np.__version__))

    nx, nz = 1024, 1024

    a = np.random.rand(nx, nz)
    b = np.zeros_like(a)

    range1(a, b, nx, nz)
    range2(a, b, 5, nx-5, 5, nz-5)
    range3(a, b, 5, nx-5, 5, nz-5)

    Nit = 1000

    ti = time.time()
    for i in range(Nit):
        range1(a, b, nx, nz)
    print('range1 : {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - ti))

    ti = time.time()
    for i in range(Nit):
        range2(a, b, 5, nx-5, 5, nz-5)
    print('range2 : {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - ti))

    ti = time.time()
    for i in range(Nit):
        range3(a, b, 5, nx-5, 5, nz-5)
    print('range3 : {:.3f}'.format(time.time() - ti))
```

There are three 'jitted' functions compiled in `nopython` mode that are barely the same... except for range arguments. On my laptop, this code returns :

```
Numba : 0.37.0
Numpy : 1.14.2

range1 : 1.736 s.
range2 : 2.406 s.
range3 : 1.723 s.
```

As you can see, there are large differences between `range1` and `range2` execution times ! After some tests, I came to the following conclusion :

- When the arguments of the `range` function are directly provided as a constant in the function to compile, or is a **variable equal to 0** (which is the case of `range1` and `range3` functions), the performances are what there are, quite good!
- On the other hand, when the arguments of the `range` function are variables, the function runs 40% slower !

I think this comes from the compilation of `range` function by numba. This leads to two main questions :

- Why exactly ?!
- How to work around this ?

Comment: BTW: Adding static typing also comes with some downsides. Numba can't see if the arrays are aligned and contignous in memory, which breaks the SIMD-vectorization. This can also have a severe impact on performance.

Comment: Indeed ! Without signatures `range1` and `range2` execute at the same speed (2.15 s. which is slower for `range1` but faster for `range2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be wraparound indexing semantics.  If you pass a negative number to e.g. `b[ix, iz]` numpy follows python and will index from the end of the array axis.

This can be seen looking at the LLVM IR.  There is a lot of noise to trim, I found the inner loop for each function by searching for the `fmul` instruction.

```
# ir for first overload
ir = next(iter(range1.inspect_llvm().values()))

# range1 inner loop
B38.us:                                           ; preds = %B38.lr.ph.us, %B38.us
  %lsr.iv8 = phi i64 [ 0, %B38.lr.ph.us ], [ %lsr.iv.next9, %B38.us ]
  %lsr.iv4 = phi i64 [ %lsr.iv2, %B38.lr.ph.us ], [ %lsr.iv.next5, %B38.us ]
  %lsr.iv = phi i64 [ %17, %B38.lr.ph.us ], [ %lsr.iv.next, %B38.us ]
  %31 = add i64 %lsr.iv10, %lsr.iv8
  %.490.us = inttoptr i64 %31 to double*
  %.491.us = load double, double* %.490.us, align 8
  %32 = add i64 %lsr.iv6, %lsr.iv8
  %.576.us = inttoptr i64 %32 to double*
  %.577.us = load double, double* %.576.us, align 8
  %.585.us = fsub double %.491.us, %.577.us
  %.595.us = fmul double %.585.us, 5.000000e-01
  %.659.us = inttoptr i64 %lsr.iv4 to double*
  store double %.595.us, double* %.659.us, align 8
  %lsr.iv.next = add nsw i64 %lsr.iv, -1
  %lsr.iv.next5 = add i64 %lsr.iv4, %arg.b.6.1
  %lsr.iv.next9 = add i64 %lsr.iv8, %arg.a.6.1
  %.338.us = icmp sgt i64 %lsr.iv.next, 1
  br i1 %.338.us, label %B38.us, label %B94.us

# range2 inner loop
B30.us:                                           ; preds = %B30.lr.ph.us, %B30.us
  %lsr.iv = phi i32 [ %1, %B30.lr.ph.us ], [ %lsr.iv.next, %B30.us ]
  %.253.025.us = phi i32 [ %arg.iz1, %B30.lr.ph.us ], [ %.323.us, %B30.us ]
  %.323.us = add i32 %.253.025.us, 1
  %.400.us = sext i32 %.253.025.us to i64
  %.401.us = add nsw i64 %.400.us, 1
  %.441.us = icmp slt i32 %.253.025.us, -1
  %.442.us = select i1 %.441.us, i64 %arg.a.5.1, i64 0
  %.443.us = add i64 %.401.us, %.442.us
  %.460.us = mul i64 %.443.us, %arg.a.6.1
  %.463.us = add i64 %.461.us, %.460.us
  %.464.us = inttoptr i64 %.463.us to double*
  %.465.us = load double, double* %.464.us, align 8
  %.489.us = add nsw i64 %.400.us, -1
  %.529.us = icmp slt i32 %.253.025.us, 1
  %.530.us = select i1 %.529.us, i64 %arg.a.5.1, i64 0
  %.531.us = add i64 %.489.us, %.530.us
  %.548.us = mul i64 %.531.us, %arg.a.6.1
  %.551.us = add i64 %.549.us, %.548.us
  %.552.us = inttoptr i64 %.551.us to double*
  %.553.us = load double, double* %.552.us, align 8
  %.561.us = fsub double %.465.us, %.553.us
  %.571.us = fmul double %.561.us, 5.000000e-01
  %.618.us = icmp slt i32 %.253.025.us, 0
  %.619.us = select i1 %.618.us, i64 %arg.b.5.1, i64 0
  %.620.us = add i64 %.619.us, %.400.us
  %.637.us = mul i64 %.620.us, %arg.b.6.1
  %.640.us = add i64 %.638.us, %.637.us
  %.641.us = inttoptr i64 %.640.us to double*
  store double %.571.us, double* %.641.us, align 8
  %lsr.iv.next = add i32 %lsr.iv, -1
  %.310.us = icmp sgt i32 %lsr.iv.next, 1
  br i1 %.310.us, label %B30.us, label %B86.us
```

Even there, a lot to parse, but in `range1` only pointer bumping / lookup / math is happening, while in range2 there is bounds checking (the `icmp` instruction), because the compiler can prove that `iz` will never be negative.

Best I can tell there is currently no way to elide this, other than starting with a compile time constant as you did.  At one point there was a `wraparound` flag for enabling / disabling, but it was [removed](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1533)